# Create an unlocked package with references to custom fields in target system

Tags: salesforcedx, unlocked-package, versioning

i'm trying to create a version of my unlocked package. It contains like 3 sobjects and 2 classes. In my objects i have fields, which are related to other custom objects from the target system. The thing is i don't have access on the configuration of those fields. I just know that they do exist.

However when i generate the version of my package i get this error:

```
MyField__c.RemoteField__c: referenceTo value of 'RemoteField_vod__c' does not resolve to a valid sObject type
```

Is there some way to tell sfdx to ignore such things? Since i know that RemoteField exists in the targeting system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow your package to include references to customization that's not part of your package or another package on which it depends, you'd need to build an [org-dependent unlocked package](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_org_dependent.htm).

This feature is in beta; it moves the validation of component references to install time instead of build time. Use the `--orgdependent` flag, e.g.,

```
sfdx force:package:create -t Unlocked -r force-app -n MyPackage --orgdependent
```

Comment: Thank you really much, this saved my life :D